# I can not type number or use number keys inside Blender

Tags: shortcut

[image]

Above is the picture of my keyboard. All of a sudden, I am unable to use my number keys inside Blender. I am not sure if I accidentally hit anything. I don't even remember.

I usually use these keys for changing 3D views, now I have to use the pie menu to change views and I also can not type any numbers into the value input box.

Comment: You probably need to go to Edit >> Preferences >> Input >> Emulate Numpad

Comment: That is classic. I have already tried that. Not working, unfortunately.

Comment: So restarted my computer has fixed the problem

Comment: me too i was able to use the upper row number keys and all of a sudden it didn't work. i closed and reopened blender, and then it worked again. lol. it is a bug and also still happens in the latest versions